# Hugging Face : Distilbert and TFTrainer giving error

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am working in Google Colab. I was trying to train the model which has following :-
input is text in english and
output is 0 or 1.

I came across following error when running `trainer.train()`(last line): `'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import DistilBertTokenizer,TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification

tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizer.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

encoded_train = tokenizer(x_train, truncation = True,padding = True,max_length = 512)
encoded_test = tokenizer(x_test, truncation = True,padding = True,max_length = 512)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(encoded_train),
    y_train
))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    dict(encoded_test),
    y_test
))

from transformers import TFTrainer,TFTrainingArguments

training_args = TFTrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=5,
    per_device_train_batch_size = 8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size = 16,
    warmup_steps=400,
    weight_decay = 0.01,
    logging_dir = './logs',
    logging_steps = 10
)
with training_args.strategy.scope():
  model = TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')

trainer = TFTrainer(model = model,
                    args = training_args,
                    train_dataset = train_dataset,
                    eval_dataset = test_dataset)

trainer.train()
```

I tried to change the version of transformers library to "4.6.0". But it raises following error `Exception encountered when calling layer 'tf_distil_bert_for_sequence_classification' (type TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification)  'NoneType' object is not callable`

Then I tried to change the version of transformers library to "4.23.1". But it raises following error `Exception encountered when calling layer` Failed to import transformers.models.distilbert.modeling_tf_distilbert because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'keras.saving.hdf5_format'`

whats the problem here ?